# How to transfer files from Ubuntu to Android via Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, file-sharing

How can I transfer my files from Ubuntu desktop to my Android phone using Wi-Fi network?

Answer (score 2):

you can install a ssh terminal app (or a scp GUI app) on Android phone, move to destination directory on Android  and from there copy with something like this command:

```
scp yourUsername@UbuntuHostnameOrIP:/path/to/your/files/filename .
```

Answer (score 2):

Flagrant copy paste from the question selected as duplicate.

Nitroshare allows drag and drop file transfer between all common operating systems including handhelds.

There are five ways to install NitroShare on Ubuntu:

---

#### Use the Archives (16.04+)

You can install the [nitroshare [image: Install nitroshare]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nitroshare) package directly from the universe repository by executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

#### Use the Stable PPA (recommended for older releases)

The stable PPA contains all of the packages necessary to run NitroShare and is considered stable enough for everyday use:

[ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/nitroshare) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

To add this PPA to your computer and install NitroShare, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

---

#### Use the Development PPA (unstable)

The development PPA contains daily builds of the packages that comprise NitroShare. Some of the features may be broken or incomplete. For this reason, its use is discouraged for any purpose other than testing or debugging:

[ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/nitroshare-dev) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

The commands for installing NitroShare from the development PPA are similar to the ones for the stable PPA.

---

#### Use the Binary Packages

Binary packages (DEBs) are provided for Ubuntu 14.04+. They can be downloaded from the official NitroShare website:

http://nitroshare.net

Once the DEB package is downloaded, you can launch it to open the Software Center to complete the installation.

---

#### Build NitroShare from Source (difficult)

If you are really ambitious, you can build NitroShare directly from source. First, you will need to ensure that all of the packages needed for building NitroShare are installed. To do that, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev libgtk2.0-dev \
  libappindicator-dev libnotify-dev
```

Visit [this page](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare/+download) and grab the `.tar.gz` download for the latest release (0.3.0 at the time of writing). Then run the following commands to build everything:

```
tar xf nitroshare-0.3.0.tar.gz
cd nitroshare-0.3.0
qmake
make
```

To install the application, run the following command:

```
sudo make install
```

You will then be able to run NitroShare using the `nitroshare` command.

If they get merged and mods see this before I do, please delete this.  I made it CW to avoid rep gain.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Android app “Xender”.

#### Android

1. Open the left menu of Xender on your phone.
2. Find the option for connect to PC, press it.
3. make sure your data service is turned OFF, otherwise, it may lag a bit
4. Select the hotspot option.

#### PC

1. Connect your PC with the hotspot i.e. same network.
2. Open your Web Browser and enter the address as per the instructions from the phone.

Now you can easily share files over.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I specifically thank full for point #3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use KDE (Kubuntu) you can use kdeconnect. Once paired there is an option to send files between computer and device.